# Logic Apps "Get file Content" Sharepoint connector timed out for files over 20MB

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

As the topic implies, my logic app having a Get File Content from a sharepoint connector,which was working fine for all the files less than 20 MB. For the files greater than **20 MB getting timeout after 4 retries** by giving the **500 Internal Server Error**

[image]

I couldn't able to find this type of [size limitations in the documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-limits-and-config).

I tried to use the chunks options but its only for upload not for retrieve

**Some Other findings :**

- A file with 17 MB got succeeded at the second retry, however for files more than 20 MB it always getting failed even after 4 retries.

RAW Output:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "source": "logic-apis-northeurope.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "3a0bf64d-2b82-4aef-92ba-ff8b101e44bb",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 500,
      "message": "Request timed out. Try again later.\r\nclientRequestId: 3a0bf64d-2b82-4aef-92ba-ff8b101e44bb\r\nserviceRequestId: e0ce569f-96aa-d08b-1c7e-20a6ccf358c3",
      "source": "https://xxxxx",
      "errors": []
    }
  }
}
```

**P.S** I'm using on-prem sharepoint, i.e gateway is already using. However no timeout logs in the gateway,which makes me to eliminate the issue is not from gateway and from logic app

Answer (score 0):

We can see logic app supports get data from sharepoint according to the on-premises data gateway in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-connection#supported-data-sources).

[image]

Then click [limits on their payload size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/data-integration/gateway/service-gateway-onprem#considerations), we can see the limits of it.
[image]

Although the document above doesn't mention the limit of 20 MB for the data response, but I think when you request the data of 17 MB, it beyond exceed the limit. So it got succeeded at the second retry but not success at the first time.

Comment: Agreed to your point in that case I should see the error logs in the gateway machine. But there is no such error is in gateway server, without getting any error at gateway logs I'm not sure to blame gateway in my case